# Linux 2.6 kernel process management

Tags: android, memory-management, process, linux-kernel, pthreads

Where can i find some information on process management in the linux 2.6 kernel. Because android uses this and i would like to find out how memory is managed, processes are scheduled and used, etc...

I want to learn more about the design principles of android. Maybe a good book on this? Maybe an article somewhere.

Thanks

Comment: It depends on what you mean by 2.6 kernel. And how much detail do you want?

Comment: @tjameson as much detail as possible. i have found some stuff, but i need to go through everything about the design of the system. For example, the newest version of the linux kernel uses CFS to schedule processes. Stuff like this. I dont know the specific version android uses, but i'm just going to assume something like 2.6.23+ in this case.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The Linux kernel version running on Android devices has many similarities with the Linux kernel version.

[Android kernel features](http://elinux.org/Android_Kernel_Features) lists the unique (changes/add-ons) kernel features that were implemented by the Android project team. These changes are not part of the standard Linux kernel.

Regarding Task Scheduling, it didn't suffer any change. So Android uses the same scheduling policy that Linux uses (CFS). For more information on CFS you should check these articles:

- [Inside the Linux 2.6 Completely Fair Scheduler - developerWorks](http://www.ibm.com/developerworks/linux/library/l-completely-fair-scheduler/)
- [Completely Fair Scheduler - Linux Journal](http://www.linuxjournal.com/magazine/completely-fair-scheduler)
- [Completely Fair Scheduler - Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Completely_Fair_Scheduler)

Regarding Memory Management, I cannot help you with that because it's too specific and I never dealt with it.

The official Google Group for everything about Android Linux kernel development can be found [here](http://groups.google.com/group/android-kernel).

The official kernel source code tree can be found [here](http://android.git.kernel.org/).

Finally, the book that I recommend to understand the Linux kernel is this [Professional Linux Kernel Architecture](http://eu.wiley.com/WileyCDA/WileyTitle/productCd-0470343435,descCd-description.html)

I hope this helps.

Comment: You might find the information at this link useful also - process and memory management is a little different on Android: http://coltf.blogspot.ie/p/android-os-processes-and-zygote.html